# How to customize eclipse clean project function?

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have a C project on Eclipse. After a successful build, I carry (cut and paste) the intermediary files (generated makefiles, object files and etc) to a specified folder by a post-build script.

When I press clean project button, the compiler does nothing normally. This is ok but my problem is how can I clean the content of my specified folder? Is there anything to be modified in order to customize clean command? Can I trigger a script when I press this button? Any other solutions exist?

Comment: Is it CDT managed or a Makefile project? I don't think you can customize `clean` in the former.

Comment: It is CDT managed.

Comment: I think you can do some trick with the `Builders` tab in the `Project Properties`. You can `Edit` the CDT builder to not run on `clean` and configure some "external tool" instead, which can be you clean command... Never done this though. Or just convert to Makefile project and have your `clean` target written there.

Answer (score 0):

Open your .cproject in text editor. Search for `cleanCommand=`. Once found, edit the command in quotes.